Definition and properties of a transpose map on an arbitrary Hilbert space $H$.
I am given the following definition and remark in my book:
Definition:
Let $A$ be a $C^{*}$-algebra and $\phi: A \rightarrow B(H)$. We say that $\phi$ is copositive if $t \circ \phi$ is completely positive, where $t$ is the transpose map on $B(H)$. $\phi$ is decomposable if $\phi$ is the sum of a completely positive and a copositive map. Otherwise $\phi$ is indecomposable.
Remark: Note that if $t^{\prime}$ is the transpose map on $B(H)$ with respect to another orthonormal basis, then there is a unitary operator $u \in B(H)$ such that $t^{\prime}=\text{Ad} u \circ t$. Thus the definition of copositive maps is independent of the choice of basis, and thus of $t$.
($\text{Ad}u$ here denotes the map $B(H) \to B(H)$ given by $\text{Ad}u(a) = u^* a u$, which is a completely positive map.)
My question is then simply whether all of this makes sense when dim $H = \infty$?
I do understand one can define the transpose map in terms of an orthonormal basis, but could someone provide me an elementary argument on how to show the result in the remark?
Also, how do I then show the basic properties of the transpose map $t$? Namely that $t \circ t = 1$ as well as the fact that $t$ is a $*$-anti-isomorphism?
